# Reading in multiple files with Javascript results in only last file being read

Tags: javascript, file, io, filereader

I have to read in a few test text files into my JavaScript code. There are 3 files, titled `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `3.txt`, each containing a single line. I wrote this piece of code which I thought would work just fine:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        console.log("Start loop")
        myFile = files.item(i);
        var myReader = new FileReader();
        myReader.readAsText(myFile);
        myReader.onload = function(e) {
            var rawLog = myReader.result;
            console.log(rawLog)
        };

    }
};

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

This results in a button on the web page that allows me to select multiple files. It is supposed to result in the following:

```
Start loop
Contents 1.txt
Start loop
Contents 2.txt
Start loop
Contents 3.txt
```

But what it outputs is the following:

```
Start loop 
Start loop
Start loop
null
null
Contents 3.txt
```

How can I generate the first one? I expect the error to be in the onload function, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `var myReader = new FileReader();` is reassigning the variable in each loop hence destroying the first instance.

I recommend you split your code to two functions to prevent the local block variable's instances from being overwritten before they are done.

```
function readFile(file) {
    var myReader = new FileReader();
  myReader.readAsText(file);
  myReader.onload = function(e) {
      var rawLog = myReader.result;
      console.log(rawLog)
  };
} 

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        myFile = files.item(i);
        readFile(myFile);
    }
};
```